# Angular radio button reset not working properly

Tags: angular

I am using below radio buttons for my form

```html
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="1" [checked]="true" name="keys" [(ngModel)]="lostkey.key">One
<input type="radio" name="keys" value="2" [(ngModel)]="lostkey.key" class="form-check-input">Both
```

I set 'One' radio button as a default checked using below code

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.lostkey.key = '1';
}
```

this is my reset button. This is working well. all forms reset. but problem is, default radio button also unchecked. therefor i re-assign it after form reset. but it did not work.

reset button (this is working correctly )

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-action btn-flat float-right"
    (click)="resetForm(reportlostkeyform)">
    <i class="fas fa-redo"></i> <span> Reset</span>
</button>
```

this is reset function

```js
resetForm(reportlostkeyform: NgForm) {
    reportlostkeyform.reset();
    this.lostkey.key = '1';
}
```

how i reassign this radio button value

Comment: You are mixing reactive forms and the `ngModel` which you shouldn't.

Comment: then how i reset radio button

Comment: You should be using `formControllerName` to bind the value.

Comment: i am using template driven form approche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resets the form control with an initial value  like this

```
 resetForm(reportlostkeyform: NgForm) {
      reportlostkeyform.reset({keys:'1'});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to reset value in setTimeout;

```
    resetForm(reportlostkeyform: NgForm) {
        reportlostkeyform.reset();
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.lostkey.key = '1';
       })    
    }
```